# Get formatted universal date / time

Tags: powershell, datetime, utc

In PowerShell you can format a date to return the current hour like this:

```
Get-Date -UFormat %H
```

And you can get a date string in UTC like this:

```
$dateNow = Get-Date
$dateNow.ToUniversalTime()
```

But how can you can get the current hour in universal time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Get-Date ([datetime]::UtcNow) -UFormat %H
```

**Up to PowerShell 7.0**, **`Get-Date` doesn't directly support formatting the current time based on its UTC value**: the formatting options apply to the *local* representation of the current time.

- In **PowerShell v7.1+** you can use the **`-AsUTC`** switch, which enable you to simplify to
  `Get-Date -AsUTC -UFormat %H`.

However, as shown above, instead of letting `Get-Date` default to the current (invariably local) time, you can pass a `[datetime]` instance as an *argument* to `Get-Date`('s positionally implied `-Date` parameter) for reformatting, and `[datetime]::UtcNow` is the current time expressed in UTC.

Comment: And is there any difference between `(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()` and  `Get-Date ([datetime]::UtcNow)` ? Running both returns the same result for me. Is the `ToUniversalTime()` approach basically doing one more method call compared to the other approach?

Comment: @iBobb, there's no difference in outcome. Yes, `[datetime]::UtcNow` - a single property access on a .NET type  - is more efficient than calling a method on the output from a _cmdlet_ (`Get-Date`), but unless you're calling this in a loop with many iterations, it probably won't make a difference in practice.